# Converting JS array UNIX date integers into JS Date objects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

Is there a way to convert UNIX epoch integers (`1402079444`, etc) in an array into JavaScript Date objects (`Date.UTC(2014,  9, 14)`, etc) using jQuery?

I'm trying to pass a large JSON array generated by PHP to Highmaps.JS, which almost works great however Highmaps expects a Date object and Date objects aren't valid JSON, so I can't generate them with PHP.

jsFiddle of my current setup here: http://jsfiddle.net/dwgLtscm/2/

(The x-axis isn't displaying dates properly because the data isn't in the proper date format).

```
[{
    "name": "Dissolved Oxygen",
    "data": [
            [1402079444,9]
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Temperature (Water)",
        "data": [
            [1401291099,9],
            [1401862547,12]
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Temperature (Air)",
        "data": [
            [1401291099,13],
            [1401862547,19]
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the Json object above, I'd try:

```
array.forEach(function (val) { 
  val.data = val.data.map(function (datum) {
    return [ new Date(datum[0] * 1000), datum[1] ];
  }
}
```

Unless I'm reading it wrong (I'm assuming data[0] is the UTC value).

(Edited based on feedback below, thanks all!)

Comment: Hm, that didn't quite work- it seemed to wipe out the data array. I added a jsFiddle so you can see what's going on!

Comment: Better multiply unix timestamp by 1000 to get new Date in javascript

Comment: You can pass the seconds * 1000 into the Date constructor and you probably meant to use map instead of forEach in the inner call. Right now your return value is being ignored

Comment: Thanks!  Good call - I was running out the door so didn't have time to test it :-\